# How to append a CR to end of all .txt files in a directory

Tags: windows-7, command-line, text-editing

Is there an easy way to do this? I'm actually combining about 500 files using `copy *.txt myoutputFile.txt`. The problem is, that command inserts the new/next file at the current/end position of the file, where I need it to be inserted on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *.txt
do
  echo -e -n '\n' >> "$f"
done
```

Comment: just `echo >> "$f"` would work... but OP's use of 'copy' infers OP is on a windows box.  Alas.  You'd have to create a file containing a CR,  then y'know... it's just painful to do it on a Windows box.  Wait! There's Quickbasic scripts in MS Word!  To the BatMobile!! (Ain't gonna do it!)  Even using a Linux LiveCD would be faster.

Comment: on windows , one place they suggest "do more"  | for %%a in (*.txt) do more %%a >>file.doc |  . and not using a .txt extention on the output so a loop doesnt occur. This method for the merging puts them on seperate lines, so no need to add to each file.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just make a quick VBScript:

```
Dim fso, folder, files
Dim strPath

Const ForAppending = 8

' Create a FileSystemObject  
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Define folder we want to list files from
strPath = "C:\members"

Set folder = fso.GetFolder(strPath)
Set files = folder.Files

' Loop through each file  
For each item In files

set textFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(item, ForAppending)

textFile.WriteLine()
textFile.Close()
Next
```